# Kubernetes pod auto-scaling

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a way to scale the pods based on pod disk I/O pressure/utilization/IO wait, rather than simple plain CPU and RAM usage?  OR maybe a combination of disk IO along with RAM and CPU usage.

something like:

```
metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: disk
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 60
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do it with [custom metrics](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#support-for-metrics-apis). So if you have something like [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/) in your cluster which is one of the most popular Kubernetes monitoring solutions you can use the [k8s-prometheus-adapter](https://github.com/DirectXMan12/k8s-prometheus-adapter)

There also a walkthrough [here](https://github.com/DirectXMan12/k8s-prometheus-adapter/blob/master/docs/walkthrough.md).

For that walkthrough, you will have to use [`Pod` type of metric](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/#autoscaling-on-multiple-metrics-and-custom-metrics) in your [HPA](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/).

For Disk I/O not sure if you mean system disk I/O or Pod disk I/O or PV disk I/O, I don't think there's a solution for all of those together. On the node side, you could scrape the I/O node metrics from the [nodeexporter](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter). I don't think there's a [pod exporter](https://github.com/brancz/kube-pod-exporter) that exports metrics at the pod level.

Also, for metrics that are not Pod type, they will have to be defined as the Object type in your HPA.

Comment: thanks , seems to be based on application specific metrics , such as number of requests , is there something built in kubernetes that we can just use out of the box like in place of cpu , use disk

Comment: Added more details basically you could get the metrics from the nodeexporter, not sure if you can get them at the pod level.

Comment: need to build your own exporter. The regular pod exporter doesn't export disk I/O metrics

Comment: Looks like the closest is pod read/write iops https://github.com/grafana/kubernetes-app#podcontainer-metrics